# Register click event for all elements by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to register a click event for all element that i found with this request :[image]

I have tried to do this, but when i click on an element, it doesn't work :

```
$("#content .item").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
         console.log("OK") ;
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="line1">
       <div class="item">
          <h2 id="item_text"><span>Affaire Bamberski : la condamnation de Krombach définitive</span></h2>
          <div class="img-div"><img id="item_img" src="http://s1.lemde.fr/image/2011/10/18/0x0/1590061_3_4d47_dieter-krombach-dans-le-box-des-accuses-le-4_73e07cc058e39baa132897442332b390.jpg" alt="" height="333px" width="500px"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <h2 id="item_text"><span>La subtile composition d'un « gouvernement de synthèse »</span></h2>
          <div class="img-div"><img id="item_img" src="http://s1.lemde.fr/image/2014/04/02/0x0/4394347_3_8c02_huit-ministres-du-nouveau-gouvernement-de_a505804b18562cdaf49b8bd649a1cfa7.png" alt="" height="333px" width="500px"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <h2 id="item_text"><span>Quand Manuel Valls prônait la sortie du nucléaire</span></h2>
          <div class="img-div"><img id="item_img" src="http://s1.lemde.fr/image/2013/12/19/0x0/4337743_3_2bdf_manuel-valls-le-17-decembre-a-reims_463507e24cd1ffd9e7dba6ffb1cff4b7.jpg" alt="" height="333px" width="500px"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though it's not the usual way to do what you want, what you posted should work. Can you post your HTML and a fiddle?

Comment: Still no element with the ID of content in your code. Does your jQuery exist within a document ready call, or at the end of the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
$(function() {
    $("#content .item").click(function(){
        console.log("OK") ;
    });
});
```

It will bind the click event to all elements matching the selector " #content .item"

Comment: Yes he can simply do that, but it will still not work since his original code was not working, but should be. It's a DOM ready problem or event delegation.

Comment: where is the #content element in your DOM ?

Comment: Just outside the line1 element

Answer (score 0):

If you generate DOM dynamically you can use delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '#content .item', function(e){
   // "this" inside this function will point to clicked DOM element
   console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for all elements without any selector.

```
$('body').children().each(function(){ 
$(this).on('click',function(){ 
  alert('dsfds'); 
    });
  });
```

or 
In your html case it will be

```
 $('#line1').children().each(function(){ 
 $(this).on('click',function(){ 
  alert('dsfds'); 
    });
  });
```